# Trying to open SQL*Plus from C# when password has a special character

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, sqlplus

I have a program which calls the process sqlplus.exe and send by arguments the user/password@tnsname but one of the DB have a "@" in the password, if I try manually connect to the database through the sqlplus terminal I can connect using quotes in the password, for example:

`CONN scott/"tig@r"@MYDB  @file.sql`

But, if I try call the Process in my program using it like a arguments with a string, I can't connect in the database. So the program show a ORA-12154.

I tried:

```
string connection = "scott/\"tig@r\"@MYDB  @file.sql";
string connection = @"scott/""tig@r""@MYDB @file.sql";
string connection = @"scott@MYDB/""tig@r"" @file.sql";
string connection = "scott@MYDB\"tig@r\"   @file.sql";
```

I already tried without the part of @file.sql, but without success.

Here is a part of the code I'm using.

```
   System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   proc.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlplus"; //open sqlplus
   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = connection + " @" + tempFile;//send by arguments the connection and the file
   proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

   proc.Start();
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using ODP.NET to execute the file?

Comment: Its a program to automate the application of SQL objects, exists many scripts/tables/procedures/packages/ some encrypted, others not. The program just select the order of application, if want it encrypted or not, create a  sql file with all selected objects in orders to apply, changing usernames to the current object owner and other stuffs. I can't do this with the odp.net

Comment: Embedding passwords is a dangerous thing.  If you're creating SQL files for others to run, you shouldn't be embedding passwords.  You should let the people who run the scripts enter the password.

Comment: @ChristopherJones The program have 2 tables, one to add TNSnames ( each person have your own ) and the second one is to add owners/passwords. So just the user who is using the program know the password to add to the program and he can't see the password. This is why I open directly the sqlplus with the selected password from the especific user.